# Is there a way to name a type for a function template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

For example, when we have a general function template, we can use the template type in the function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
  T t;
  ...
}
```

Now, imagine specializations of this function template:

```
template <>
void foo<MySpecialType>()
{
  T t; // Does not compile, no knowledge of formal template argument T
  MySpecialType t2; // This is OK, but I have to mention MySpecialType again
}

template <>
void foo<MySpecialType2>()
{
  T t; // Does not compile, no knowledge of formal template argument T
  MySpecialType2 t2; // This is OK, but I have to mention MySpecialType2 again
}
```

Notice that in both specializations above, I have to mention the type of the template argument being specialized on by name inside the body of the functions. I would prefer to use a more generic place holder (i.e., T) rather than repeat the type being specialized upon (perhaps multiple times) within the bodies of the function template specializations.

If there was a way to use T or create an alias at the point of actual specialization function definition, that would be great. I know I can do this via a type alias inside the actual function body:

```
template<>
void foo<MySpecialType>
{
  using T=MySpecialType; // But then I still repeat the type at least once
  ...
```

I would prefer specialization conventions like:

```
// Warning: Not valid C++
template<>
void foo<T=MySpecialType>
{
  T t;
  ...
```

Or:

```
// Warning: Not valid C++
template<T>
void foo<MySpecialType>
{
  T t;
  ...
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What would `T` be in that context?

Comment: T is the type of the actual function template argument.

Comment: I'm curious why you are concerned about this.  I'm not trying to be flippant -- I suspect I know why, and it might effect how best to approach this.

Comment: @John, Redundant mention of types (by name) can lead to desynchronization when the type is renamed or another type is used. This sometimes causes very difficult to diagnose compile time errors and in the worst possible scenario causes no compile-time errors (e.g., if the types are very similar) and is discovered later at run-time.

Comment: There is no redundant mention of types. You are specializing your templates.

Comment: Are you talking about making copy-paste code writing easier?

Comment: If I have to mention a type by name more than once, there are multiple mentions of the type. Whether these multiple mentions are viewed as "redundant" is up for debate. In my response to John above, I claim that they are redundant from a maintenance perspective.

Comment: When you say "more than once" are you referring to within a single specialization, or across all specializations?

Comment: @John, I am referring to mentioning a type by name once per specialization. Since each specialization is for a different type, it must mention its type at least once. I am trying to see if this "at least once" can also be made into "at most once" as well in order to avoid redundant type mentions by name.

Comment: Ah, where one mention is in the angle brackets, and the other is in the actual code?  If so, I think your answer is "no."

Comment: Further, you seem to be looking at the unspecialized implementation as the standard you're trying to achieve in your specializations.  But you have to "mention" `T` at least twice there as well.

Comment: The problem of desychronization makes no sense in a function specialization for `MySpecialType`: if it's possible to replace `MySpecialType` with `MyOtherSpecialType` without rewriting the entire function, then you probably don't need specialization.

Comment: @John, mentioning T multiple times is OK. The formal template argument name T does not change, it is just a placeholder. In practice, what changes is the type of the actual template argument used when a template is instantiated or specialized (e.g., because a class gets renamed).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct bar
{
    using Type = T;

    static void foo();
};

template <typename T>
void bar<T>::foo()
{
    Type t;
    // ...
}

template <>
void bar<MySpecialType>::foo()
{
    Type t;
    // ...
}

template <>
void bar<MySpecialType2>::foo()
{
    Type t;
    // ...
}

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    bar<T>::foo();
}
```

But do you really need it?

Comment: This appears to not answer the question at all?

Comment: @JohnDibling Why? Now one can use `Type` in `bar<...>::foo()` specializations.

Comment: You seem to be answering the question, "How do I specialize a template?"  That wasn't the question.  Perhaps I've misunderstood someone.

Comment: @JohnDibling I answer the question "How to get a template parameter type in template specializations in the uniform way". My solution achieves this using an auxiliary class and `using Type = T;` directive in it.

Comment: @JohnDibling I have added a couple lines of code to my answer. Please, see, does it become clearer?

Comment: Rename the formal parameter to `T_` and the `typedef` to `typedef T_ T;`, and the OP gets the name `T` that they want.

Comment: @Yakk Do you think that names of a template parameter and its `typedef` are really significant here?

Comment: @constructor the OP sure did, as this is all about renaming types to `T`. ;)  Personally, specializations are specializations: rarely justified on function `template`s.  Use traits classes and overloads instead.  If code is so identical you want to call the type `T` or whatever uniform name, there is something wrong.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I completely agree with you that this is a very strange and suspicious question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is doable. The following is a working solution that utilizes partial specialization and as such a class template containing a static function:

```
template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct foo_impl
{
    static void bar()
    {
        ::std::cout << "T\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct foo_impl<T, typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type>
{
    static void bar()
    {
        ::std::cout << "int\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    foo_impl<T>::bar();
}
```

Comment: `::std::enable_if<::std::is_same`: here is a digraph. The code should not compile.

Comment: @Constructor Unless you use c++11

Comment: Could you provide a link on that?

Comment: @Constructor [A GCC bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54526) cites the exact part of the standard: 2.5§3 bullet 2